# Rescale Bootstrap columns to be the same height as another column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

So I have been having to struggle with this for quite a while, I am not sure how to resize the carousel so that it matches the column height of the blockquote and I can't seem to centre the image div inside the carousel. If I have a large image, the carousel becomes taller than the text.

I would like image1 to be scaled to the same **height** as image2 whilst also keeping the same aspect ratio.

Here is my code:

Best to view it fullscreen.

```css
.project {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.image1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #3178bf;
}

.image2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #3178bf;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="project">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <blockquote class="blockquote text-left description">
        <h3 style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">
          Title
        </h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Text goes here
          </li>
          <li>
            Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
            <br> Text goes here
          </li>
        </ul>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          Date
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div id="carousel4" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel4" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel4" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="image1" alt="Test image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel4" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel4" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One solution would be to use JS to find height of the biggest element and resize all others accordingly. Though I have used it often, it feels kinda hacky. Last resort.

Comment: Yeah, I started doing this but I have multiple carousels and multiple images in each. This would require me to update the column height every time the image is changed for each carousel and I didn't really think that was appropriate.